# Selected text date string - add to calendar option

Tags: javascript, html, date

Bit of a wide question so feel free to ask for elaboration if needed but after some Googling I couldn't find an answer.

More curious than an actual need.

Is there a way of adding a tag, attribute (such as type=date) or JS (such as converting to a date object) to a text date string, like "Tuesday 3rd May, 2pm" that allows the user to select it and add it to their calendar?

Much like I can select an address text string and Google gives me the option to find that location on Google Maps.

Not looking for a concrete answer necessarily just some direction so I can have a play around.

Comment: this may be of some help, there is a api for adding things to your google calendar. Converting a text string to a date should be simple using Date.parse() as long as you know the format prior to trying to convert it, documentation can be found on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse. Documentation for calendar api can be found on https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with this:

```html
<input type="date" />

<script>
    const input = document.querySelector('input');

    input.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
        const date = new Date(target.value).toDateString();
        console.log(date);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer but was more looking to convert a text string of a date into a "calendar object" for lack of a better / correct word.

Comment: @Robgit28 You'll have to either use an external package or write your own "calendar object"